# Equivalent of python's range in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I want to know what is the equivalent code for the python's range(start,stop,step=1). If anyone knows, I am really grateful for the help.

Comment: a for loop. Please show your research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this code instead, but you need to create a function first:

```js
var number_array = [];

function range(start,stop) {
    for (i =start; i < (stop+1); i++) {
        number_array.push(i);
    }
    return number_array;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't have a range method.
Please refer to the [Looping Code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Looping_code) section in MDN's JavaScript guide
for further info.

Also, try doing some research or giving examples of what you'd like to achieve before asking such questions. A code is sample or a simple description would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The lazily evaluated version of `range()`; what used to be `xrange()`;

```js
function* range(start, end, step) {
  const numArgs = arguments.length;
  if (numArgs < 1) start = 0;
  if (numArgs < 2) end = start, start = 0;
  if (numArgs < 3) step = end < start ? -1 : 1;

  // ignore the sign of the step
  //const n = Math.abs((end-start) / step);
  const n = (end - start) / step;

  if (!isFinite(n)) return;

  for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    yield start + i * step;
}

console.log("optional arguments:", ...range(5));
console.log("and the other direction:", ...range(8, -8));
console.log("and with steps:", ...range(8, -8, -3));

for(let nr of range(5, -5, -2)) 
  console.log("works with for..of:", nr);

console.log("and everywhere you can use iterators");
const [one, two, three, four] = range(1,4);
const obj = {one, two, three, four};
console.log(obj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```